# How do I access the F8 Bootmenu while booting a Windows 2008R2 KVM Guest VM?

Tags: linux, kvm-virtualization, virsh

Stupid question but this doesn't work, seems like it should. Is there a trick to access a booting Guest VM's bootmenu using `KVM`? I'm running the VM using `virt-manager` 0.8.7. `KVM` server is a **CentOS 6.3** box running `qemu-kvm-0.12.1.2-2.295.el6_3.8.x86_64`. Guest is Windows 2008R2.

I added this to the Guest VM's XML:

```
% virsh edit DR-01
...
  <os>
    <type arch='x86_64' machine='rhel5.4.0'>hvm</type>
    <boot dev='hd'/>
    <bootmenu enable='yes'/>
  </os>
```

Doesn't give me the ability to hit the <kbd>F8</kbd> key. Any ideas how to accomplish this?

Comment: I just press F8.

Comment: If F8 doesn't work try holding Ctrl while the VM is still in it's "BIOS" until the boot menu comes up.

Comment: @Michael Hamton: Yeah I tried that and it's not working.

Comment: I just tried fullscreen and hitting F8 and that worked, if it's windowed it doesn't.

Comment: @slm you should write this as an answer to your question and accept it to help future visitors.

Comment: Ctrl + F8 doesn't have any effect either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick seems to be that you have to put the guest's `virt-manager` session in fullscreen mode. Here are the steps that I took to get this working:

**1.** Put guest in fullscreen mode

[image: Guest VM in fullscreen]

**2.** Start the Guest VM

[image: start guest VM]

**3.** Focus the VM immediately once it starts up by clicking inside its window w/ mouse

**4.** Start hitting the <kbd>F8</kbd> key

**5.** Now you'll see the Guest VM's bootmenu

[image: Guest VM's bootmenu]

**EDIT #1**

If you're still having issue as I said in the question originally and as [@dyasny mentioned in his answer](https://serverfault.com/a/463148/2518), try giving yourself more time during boot up of the guest VM by adding the following to the guest's domain XML via the `virsh` command:

```
% virsh edit DR-01
...
<os>
  <type arch='x86_64' machine='rhel5.4.0'>hvm</type>
  <boot dev='hd'/>
  <bootmenu enable='yes'/>
</os>
```

Comment: actually, the more complex virt management solutions (RHEV/oVirt) have an option to start a VM in paused mode. This way, you have the console open and ready for F8 (or whatever else) you hit play, and easily switch to the console without a hurry

Answer (score 2):

if you enable the boot menu in VM boot options, it will provide an extra delay, so you can refocus.